# Display Json using JS trough HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, web

I want to display the id info from my JSon, I did the database and the backend  with PHP, and I am using JS with HTML to dispaly it in the browser.I am a little stuck at the moment.
That is the backend, I linked it the databse with Apache:

```
?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
include "db_connection.php";
$myJSON = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM playas")) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $myJSON[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myJSON);
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

in other document i have the js and the html:

```
var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow'
};

function getData() {
    fetch("http://localhost/practice/backend/playas.php")
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(myRawData => {
            const myJsonData = JSON.parse(myRawData)
            console.log(myJsonData);
            document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = myJsonData;
        })

    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    for (let i = 0; i < myJsonData.length(); i++) {

    }

}
getData();
```

I tried some stuff and I know that a have to iterate the JSon, but it only show right now this:
`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

I also know that I have to use `document.getElementById("").innerHTML` or something similar.

the JSON:

```
[{"id":"1","nombres_playas":"deveses","numero_hamacas":"10","telefono":"916344412","mail":"deveses@mail.com"}, 
{"id":"2","nombres_playas":"bolonia","numero_hamacas":"13","telefono":"916552312","mail":"bolonia@mail.es"},
{"id":"3","nombres_playas":"granadella","numero_hamacas":"5","telefono":"965431222","mail":null},
{"id":"4","nombres_playas":"malvarosa","numero_hamacas":"21","telefono":"","mail":"malvarosa@yahoo.es"}]
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your JSON? sounds like you need to iterate over the results in php.

Comment: If you need HTML, then have your PHP script generate HTML, not JSON.

Comment: _Side note:_ You can change to `.then(response => response.text())` to `.then(response => response.json())`, then you don't need to parse it manually in the callback function.

Comment: 1. you need `response.json()` instead, that way you have the parsed object in the next `.then()` callback. 2. fetch is async, so your for loop runs before the JSON is loaded, and `myJsonData` doesn't even exist outside the callback. 3. Forcing an array into a string prints the elements separated by commas; forcing an object into a string prints `[object Object]`. (that's why you get the result you see)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the json like this:

```
var json = [{"id":"1","nombres_playas":"deveses","numero_hamacas":"10","telefono":"916344412","mail":"deveses@mail.com"},{"id":"2","nombres_playas":"bolonia","numero_hamacas":"13","telefono":"916552312","mail":"bolonia@mail.es"},{"id":"3","nombres_playas":"granadella","numero_hamacas":"5","telefono":"965431222","mail":null},{"id":"4","nombres_playas":"malvarosa","numero_hamacas":"21","telefono":"","mail":"malvarosa@yahoo.es"}];

let string = "";
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];
  
    string += obj.nombres_playas+' - '+obj.telefono+'<br/>';
 }
 
 document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = string;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zeyuv18w/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the [Object] because you can't render a javascript object directly to HTML.
If you want to show the complete JSON, you can stringify it and then put in HTML as below:

```
document.getElementById("elementId").innerHTML(JSON.stringify(myJsonData))
```

That's all you need to do!